# How to use the Navigation Graph without loading a fragment by default?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I need to use the navigation component and have it already set up. The navigation graph requires a `startDestination` which loads that fragment by default upon creation. However, I have a fragment which I only want to show after an event is triggered within the existing screen. How could I leave the fragment container empty until I'm ready to navigate to it?

Comment: You will load a specific fragment but you dont know when or you dont know Which fragment you gonna load until the event?

Comment: What is 'the existing screen' and its relationship to the `NavHostFragment`?

Comment: The existing screen is an activity with fragments already loaded. When an event is triggered, via an option selected on a context menu, I need to show the new fragment in a navigation fragment container overlayed over everything, but not full screen. This fragment has a search field, 2 tabs, and a recycler view. Then once an item on one of the tabs is selected, I will swap that fragment out with a new fragment. Also, the user has the option of going back to the previous search fragment.

Comment: The fragments in the existing screen aren't using the navigation component. I'm adding new functionality that has it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your xml file declare your container as empty navigation host

```
     <fragment
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

then in your activity you can set your graph progmatically

```
        val navHost = NavHostFragment()
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.container, navHost)
               .commit()
        val graph = navHost.navController.navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.my_navigation)
        graph.startDestination = R.id.my_fragment
        navHost.navController.graph = graph
```

you can check this [link](https://medium.com/@anoopg87/set-start-destination-for-navhostfragment-dynamically-b072a29bfe49)

Comment: Thank you! A good idea to build the fragment container without specifying the host. I had tried to omit the `startDestination` but received an error, so assumed everything was required. As far as your code, I'm getting an error: _java.lang.IllegalStateException: NavController is not available before onCreate()_. The following code seems to work though: `val navController = findNavController(R.id.container)
navController?.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Add **app:allowStacking=false** to xml file having tag <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView> or <fragment>. This will avoid loading fragment which set at start destination.
```

```java
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                android:id="@+id/setting_nav_host_fragment"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:allowStacking="false"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/settings_graph" />
```

Comment: What API level is your answer valid from?

Comment: It will work for most of Api level which support navigation component! My api level was 33.